# Proper way to terminate question?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736602/unknown-type-name-uint8-t-uint32-t-uint64-t-size-t?noredirect=1#comment55244150_33736602) where I was getting compilation errors due to non-standard types in C from a non-standard library.

My real issue at the time was trying to get the library that I mentioned working and my troubleshooting the problems led me to the problem I posed in that question. However I managed to solve the library problems I was having (proper referencing of library in makefile) but it does not exactly solve the specific problem that was addressed in the question (which I am unsure how directly linked to my root problem this actually was, I'm asking here in part because of this uncertainty).

How should I terminate this question? Should I answer my own question with what I fixed it with but is completely different to what the question's premise is even though others have made better, more relevant hints that would be more useful to future visitors (if any) to the question?

EDIT: I also want to make clear that it's a question I want to be seen as 'not active' as it's not longer a problem for me which is why I'm not sure how to terminate it without deleting it.

Comment: Why do you not want to delete it?

Comment: If you can't improve it, and can't answer it in a way that makes sense with the question as asked, your choices should be either improve the question, or delete it.

Comment: As long there are no upvoted answers, you can just delete it. Otherwise improve your question to describe your problem better (which was actually done poorly), and write an answer yourself.

Comment: _" I want to be seen as 'not active' as it's not longer a problem for me ..."_ You seem to miss a crucial point of the site. Stack Overflow isn't about solving **your** problems, but building up a repository of Q&A that will be helpful for anyone in future research.

Comment: _"more relevant hints that would be more useful to future visitors"_ Sorry, you already seem to dig that point.